# Masking a subdomain using to a domain just like Google Sites

Tags: redirect, dns, subdomain

I have a website hosted at xyz.abc.com.

However I want people to see only abc.com in the address bar. Currently I just redirect abc.com to xyz.abc.com and that changes the URL to xyz.abc.com.

In other words, I want to mask the subdomain just like Google Sites does (not cloak it using frames and iframes). Please help me with a solution. Thanks...

Comment: are you on linux? do you have access to .htaccess?

Comment: Are xyz.abc.com and abc.com on same server (I mean same hosting account)?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to place frames at abc.com.

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame name="main_frame" src="http://xyz.abc.com/">
</frameset>
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use a frameset.

Comment: uh.. that'd be a tough thing to do. I'll do some research. If I'm successful, I'll surely show up.